# Capturing first click event on a canvas without focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, dom-events

I have a Canvas which responds to `mousedown` events on it.  I am then adding an input element to the DOM, and absolutely positioning this so it is over the canvas.

After then user has clicked on the input element, and entered some text, they then click back to the canvas.  My problem is that this first click merely sets the focus back to the canvas, but is not registered as a `mousedown` event on the canvas element.

What can I do to make sure that the first click is registered?

Comment: Is there any way you could show some code so we can get a better feel for how it's structured? Do you have access to JQuery? If so, then my initial response would be to use the `trigger` (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

Answer (score 1):

How are you attaching the events? This should "just work", unless there are extenuating circumstances.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bSpe4/

Depending on what your code looks like, giving your canvas a tab index value may also help.

`theCanvas.tabIndex = 0; // might fix your particular issue`

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps there is more going on then - the tabindex trick didn't have any affect.   It's difficult to post code here, because it's spread about a bit, but I'll see if I can put something together.

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly this problem. I needed to listen for both left and right clicks and was using a `mousedown`.

In case anyone finds this as I just have. I "solved" it by attaching the event to `mouseup` rather than `mousedown`.

That way the focus happens when on `mousedown` and the event triggers on `mouseup` which is fine for what I'm doing.